# Can I apply name-spacing to other directories when versioning Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versioning

I have finished building a Rails API, so far so good I have versioned it following some of the tutorials I found.

The issue I have is that I did notice that most tutorials covered applying version on controllers only.

My question is that is it possible to apply the same format to models, specs by prefixing them with `v1` if I am working with it at the moment? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a situation where you need versioned models?

Comment: Not at the moment @JagdeepSingh, I was curious if it is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your underlying model structure shouldn't change based an API version.  A versioned API is only meant to change how models are accessed, not change the models themselves.